# How to import and fetch data using sqlite in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

I am going to make a dictionary. so i need to import a sqlite database to my flutter project, I used following codes , but it gives me exceptions. My database on the **assets** folder and also it has a table called **words**. i used following codes

pubspect.yaml

```
 assets:
- assets/logos/
- assets/svg/
- assets/sinhalaDictionary.db



import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

Future<void> copyDatabase() async {
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
  var path = join(databasesPath, 'sinhalaDictionary.db');

  // Check if the database already exists in the device's file system
  if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(path) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound) {
    // Copy the database from assets to the device
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/sinhalaDictionary.db');
    List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
 }
}

Future<void> fetchDataFromDatabase() async {
  // Open the database
 Database database = await openDatabase(
    join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'sinhalaDictionary.db'),
  );

  // Query your database here
  List<Map> results = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM words');

  // Print the results to the console
  for (Map result in results) {
    print(result);
  }

  // Close the database when done
 await database.close();
 }`
```

[exception-table not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7lc3.jpg)

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7DvT.jpg)

```
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(no such table: words (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM words) sql 'SELECT * FROM words' args [])
```

i have been trying to fix this issue for more than 1 day. please tell me how to fix this.

i need to import a sqlite database and need to fetch data on my project

Comment: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md

Comment: Are your assets in pubspec.yaml in the same format as in your question? because if so, its the wrong format. you need to fix up the indents. Also double check if your assets folder is inside lib, then you need to add 'lib/assets'

Comment: @Texv sorry it was a mistake. i fixed it

Comment: you miss-understood me, Im talking about the spacing of the lines. The dash starts on left, it needs to have 2 spaces first. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647544/i-cant-add-the-image-from-assets-file-in-flutter/65648095#65648095

Comment: are you talking about this `
- assets/sinhalaDictionary.db
`

Comment: bro,. it doesn't have any issue. it has 2 spaces. if it has an error. we cannot access to the database, and cannot update pubspect.yaml.. everything is ok. it connect to the database, but it doesn't read it well